# Element nested in child moves on hover even when absolutely positioned relative to child's parent?

Tags: html, css, hover, position, absolute

I'm trying to keep a nested element still and positioned absolute to its grandparent when the grandparent's hovered and the parent's moved. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried adding hover transitions to the element in opposite directions but it still moves.

Making the element a sibling of its parent so that the hierarchy is just 2 levels deep attains the visual effect but the structure needed for later is different. Hoping for a simple solution without needing to insert HTML or display none on elements.

https://codepen.io/y30b10/pen/WNKGKQz

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child-1,
.child-2 {
}

.child-1 {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child-2 {
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.child-2:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -10%);
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2">
    <h1 class="">Absolute positioned element</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really a great solution with margin, but is this essentially what you want the *end result* to look like? https://codepen.io/verarera/pen/xxJEyOa?editors=1100 I'm still trying to grasp what you are looking for.

Comment: @vera margin will work in the way that transform doesn't - but you have some doubt??

Comment: @AHaworth I don't think margin should be abused this way since it may cause some headaches later on when you *do* need to use margin. Also, sometimes doing this to move elements doesn't work...